# Autolayout, make 4 views have same width using storyboard?

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]

I am trying to figure out to make these 4 views contained in one superview have the exact same width as the superview changes its width.

I am working in storyboard. I tried to use the equal widths but I am probably not doing it right.

How can I do this in storyboard?

Thanks

Comment: Show or explain in detail what you actually tried. Also, show or explain in what way that failed to achieve what you want. Setting equal widths constraints is **part** of the proper solution. You also have to add other constraints, too, though. You need to set them so they are next to each other and set the ones on each end to touch the corresponding ends of the superview. You also have to set the vertical constraints.

Comment: ok, I will try to work on showing what I did better. It might take me a while but I'll try. Thank you

Comment: Set one of the view to have a width equal to a multiple (0.25) of it's superview's width and then set the other view's widths equal to the first views width. Then set all the other constraints to line them up next to one another and have the the appropriate heights.